# Why should I use BeginWrite instead of Write?

Tags: c#, networkstream

I am working on a service that manages up to 30.000 remote devices.

Doing some load tests it seems like the async method BeginWrite use more resources then regular Write (I think due to the overhead needed to create a callback thread); on the other hand, the Write method always returns faster then BeginWrite.

So my question is: what is the reason to prefer BeginWrite?

Another question is: any reason to set a WriteTimeout for sync Write? In which cases the Write method doesn't generate an immediate exception (due to closed socket, for example) but doesn't complete in a reasonable time?

**EDIT**: I have a set of worker threads (32 or 64), so I send data to 500-1000 devices at once and Write seems to work better than BeginWrite.

**EDIT 2**: after a little search I understand that sync Write hangs only if the write buffer is full. Default write buffer size is 8KB, and I just send 1-2KB of data at once, so in my application Write should never hangs and it is performing better that BeginWrite. I set a security WriteTimeout of 1 second.

Comment: Are you sending data to all remote devices at once? Can you show us the code of your test?

Comment: I send data to 500-1000 devices at once.

Comment: It is a very very big project so showing code is not simple.

Comment: Imagine 32 worker threads fighting for time on the cores and for access to the network... The overhead of scheduling these waiting threads might have a significant effect on the performance.

Comment: I agree with you, so I come to the second question: how to manage write timeout to sync Write? If a write operations hangs (but why this should happens?) I never go on with Write to other devices managed by the same working thread.

Answer (score 2):

Scalability.

Synchronous calls block the thread while they complete. Async methods don't. Depending on how many concurrent requests you're going to be dealing with, this may matter.

Comment: This is the reason I have tried to use async write, but what I have seen in my tests is that Write works better even with lots (500-1000) of contemporary write operations (but on different socket, so not concurrent writes).

Comment: Well, always measure because YMMV. Still, 1000 may be your max now but in the future... And it's not the specific channel (socket in this case) you're trying to conserve - it's threads. They're a finite resource.